# Conditional Formatting - Subscript Out of Range

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am new to conditional formatting. I am basing this off of recorded macro where I have cleaned up the code. It makes its way through one iteration but throws a "Subscript out of range" error. Would someone please help me understand whats happening here.

```
    Dim arrAisles, arrCol
    Dim rng As Range
    
    arrAisles = Array("C9:E", "H9:J", "M9:O")
    arrCol = Array(5, 10, 15)
    
    
    Set rng = Sheets("Main").Range(arrAisles(i) & GetLastRow("Main", arrCol(i)))
    With rng
     For i = 0 To 2
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
                xlConditionValueLowestValue
             .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
            .Color = 8109667
            .TintAndShade = 0
            
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
                xlConditionValuePercentile
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
             .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
            .Color = 8711167
            .TintAndShade = 0
            
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
                xlConditionValueHighestValue
             .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
            .Color = 7039480
            .TintAndShade = 0
     Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Move `For i = 0 To 2` before `Set rng = ... ` and `Next i` outside the `End With`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that line. It throws an error on:
                .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
                    xlConditionValueLowestValue

Comment: What's the purpose if the `i` loop?  Please describe exactly what the code is intended to do - difficult to suggest changes otherwise...

Comment: arrAisles = Array("C9:E", "H9:J", "M9:O") - I need conditional formatting on these columns going to last row. I can not hard set it because the data moves, so I need to Call my conditional formatting function at the end of my code.

Comment: make sure you clear on existing formats on that range in your code first, before trying to add new ones.

Comment: @TimWilliams the `i` is meant to iterate the two arrays that then builds the range objects to act upon

Comment: I used, .ClearFormats and I still get the error

Comment: I don't see where you actually add a formatcondition (unless it already exists?)

Comment: I was using .ClearContents but it leaves the borders still over the previous pulled data, so I switched over to .delete. The problem with delete is that it removes the conditional formatting.

Comment: I figured it out. I should of gone about it like this from the start..I manually inserted the formatting to last row, then in the code I removed the borders and reapplied